# Do Himalayan Salt Lamps remove airborne contaminates?

Tags: environmental-health, himalayan-salt

While indirectly related to [Himalayan salt caves](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7490/can-a-himalayan-crystal-salt-cave-reduce-stress) due to their sourcing, Himalayan Salt Lamps are not quite the same.  These lamps are sold for the dual purposes of mood lighting and supposed health benefits due to the generation of negative ions that "[...help remove airborne contaminates.](http://www.natural-salt-lamps.com/negative-ions.html)" and "help mitigate EMF fields".  Sometimes salt lamps are also alleged to work in the same way as an [air ioniser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_ioniser).

Obviously, the aesthetics of salt lamps are subjective and can't be tested; however, is there any evidence the support the claim that the lamps remove airborne contaminates?

Comment: @Chad - I'm not seeing what the duplicate is, one is about an entire cave of salt where as this question is about salt lamps.

Comment: @Chad - It doesn't appear to, the proponents of salt lamps are claiming that ionization is the primary mechanism of action where as the proponents of salt caves are claiming that the inhalation of airborne salt is the primary mechanism of action.

Comment: I have focused the question on the airborne contaminantes because I think that provides a better claim to be skeptical of.  If you include the EMF Fields I think you will need to prove that EMF Fields provide enough of a threat in homes to need to be mitigated.

Comment: @Chad - Good point, the EMF fields doesn't show up as often as the general "airborne contaminates" claim do.